# Pytorch: Quantize weights to unisgned 8 bit

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, quantization

I am trying to quantize the weights of the BERT model to unsigned 8 bits, and working with PyTorch. It works well with int8 datatype, but throws an error for unsigned int8 bits.

Am using the 'dynamic_quantize' function for the same.

```
quantized_model = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic( model, {torch.nn.Linear}, dtype=torch.quint8 )
```

But it throws the error 'AssertionError: The only supported dtypes for dynamic quantized linear are qint8 and float16 got: torch.quint8'.

Is there any specific reason for this not to be supported? Could I use any other method to quantize the weights to unsigned int8 bits?

Here is a link to the colab sheet:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14G_jdLuZD5846jUDZUdGNf1x0DMz8GKK?usp=sharing

Thanks!